# how to get html select to show selected value

Tags: html

Hi I have a html select tag like this:

```
<select name = "options>
  <option value = "235">apples</option>
  <option value = "264">oj</option>
  <option value = "133">banana</option>
</select>
```

If I do it like this, when the page first loads, it will show apples.

However, the value of options might already be set. The value might be set to oj. In that case, I want to show oj instead of apples.

Also, if I select oj and I refresh the page, it will show apples again instead of oj.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `selected` attribute: `<option value="264" selected="selected">oj</option>`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `selected` attribute to the option you want..

```
<select name = "options">
  <option value = "235">apples</option>
  <option value = "264" selected>oj</option>
  <option value = "133">banana</option>
</select>
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/JqXQL/1/

Comment: but you cant do that staticly. it could be set to anything in the backend.
it could also be banana instead of oj

Comment: @SuperString, your backend will need to add the attribute to the option, based on user selection.. what is the backend ? and how do you create the options ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the attribute `selected` to the option you would like to appear selected, like this:

```
<option value = "264" selected="selected">oj</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `selected="selected"` for XHTML compliance.

```
<select name = "options">
  <option value = "235">apples</option>
  <option value = "264" selected = "selected">oj</option>
  <option value = "133">banana</option>
</select>
```